# sharing user's location with other users

Tags: android, maps

In my app I have a map that should contain all the connected users.
Every time a user connects to the app I draw a marker that represents this user.
My problem is that every user can see only himself on the map so I need to find a way to share all users current location in order to draw on every phone all the connected users.
Any ideas?
Thanks, Nirel.

Answer (score 1):

Use some BaaS-provider for storing locations of connected users - every user could connect to the cloud-base and retrieve locations of other users. For instance you could use [enter link description here](http://parse.com) or [enter link description here](http://kinvey.com) they have special classes to store location data